# Moving blocks in backend product add form

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

for example I want to move the block "images and videos" before content block.

I couldn't find a way to do this:

Any hint in that direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

this file override in your module `vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml` and add your sort order.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <htmlContent name="gallery" sortOrder="80">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Images And Videos</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </htmlContent>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just hint then [layout instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)